# Plesk: Using nodejs results in an error "Cannot find module 'phusion_passenger/line_reader'

Tags: node.js, passenger, plesk, phusion

Having an issue with Plesk and nodejs-extension using phusion passenger.

My Plesk Version: **Plesk Obsidian 18.0.31 Update #2**

My OS: **Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS**

Using **nodejs 12.4.0** which is primarly installed via plesk.

I set up two domains. On both i run npm install via the plesk ui. Everything works and nothing results in an error, until I head to the domains, I got following error messages within development mode:

**On domain 1**:

[Domain 1 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUd2.png)

**On domain 2**

[Domain 2 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY4v7.png)

Its a bit confusing since everything seems to work fine.

I have already tried to set an Environment variable in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/phusion-passenger.conf`:

```
passenger_env_var NODE_PATH /usr/share/passenger/node;
```

Reason is that in phusion passengers github somebody recommends this within an issue. And in `/usr/share/passenger/node/phusion-passenger/` I found the `line_reader.js`.

But this doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out, that the path-variables aren't correct for phusion to work. After editing them hard in the code everything works fine.

I am still not happy about this solution. So if anyone knows another option to solve this. please suggest.

Comment: *I am still not happy about this solution.* Then your question may get better coverage if you 'unaccept' your self-answer.